# jquery ColdFusion return

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I want to return the jquery results separately so I can build a table out of them

This already works

```
<script>            
            $(document).ready(function() {            
            
                    $result = $("#result");
                    
                    $("#options").change(function(e) {
                        var selected = $(this).val();
                        console.log('change:', selected);
                        if(selected === '--') return;
                        $.get("/inside/fusebox/view/communications/locations/getsite.cfc?method=dostuff", {input:selected}, function(res) {
                        
                            $result.html(res);
                        },"JSON");
                    });
            })
            </script>
```

It shows the return as one long string

However, I have them separated in the return.

```
<cfreturn "#siteinfo.photourl#,#siteinfo.siteid#,#siteinfo.sitename#,#siteinfo.address#,#siteinfo.city#,#siteinfo.state#,#siteinfo.zipcode#" />
```

so what appears on the page of one long sentence

in this div

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

It works.

I just really don't know how to go about and separate the results so I can build a table as a display.

```
<table> <tr>
        <td><div id = "siteid"></div></td>
        <td><div id = "sitename"></div></td>
        </tr>
<tr><td><div id = "siteaddress"></div></td>
        <td><div id = "sitecity"></div></td>
        <td><div id = "siteastate"></div></td>
        <td><div id = "sitezipcode"></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: 1. Consider returning the data as an array or arrays or an array of struct. 2. Also consider using a too like datatables.net

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO! Hope you like it here.

You're better of returning JSON such as:

```
[{"photourl":"...", "siteid": "...", "sitename": "<sitename>", "city": "XX", "state": "ZZ", "zipcode": "00000"}];
```

Then you would replace

```
$result.html(res);
```

With

```
const siteinfo = JSON.parse(res)[0];
with(siteinfo) {
    $('#siteid').text(siteid);
    $('#sitename').text(sitename);
    //etc
}
```

If you intend to return multiple structs (objects) which will result in multiple rows consider using classes, eg `.siteid`, `.sitename` ...., instead of ids.

Comment: Thank you so much. However I must have missed something. I changed the function return to ```<cfreturn "I was sent: #siteinfo.sitename#">````  and nothing happened. I removed the $result.html(res); and replaced it with exactly what you suggested. Thank you

Comment: Assuming you have a variable `sites` in CF which is type array of struct then what you need to return is `SerializeJSON(sites)`

Comment: TY it is putting me on the right track. Still working on it

Comment: @djb80 feel free to let me know if you have any further questions.